# Windows 8 hides / data copied from a Windows 7 computer. Or am I losing my mind?

Tags: windows

I've had this happen two different times:

1. I backed up a client's hard drive to my large backup drive.
2. I do initial Windows 8 setup on new Laptop.
3. I pull the hard drive from the Windows 8 laptop and attach drive to my computer via SATA.
4. I copy LARGE amounts of data into a folder (C:\Users\Public\RECOVERED)
5. Install laptop drive back into Windows 8 laptop.
6. Data is GONE! Also drive acts as if there is REALLY bad drive corruption!?

Am I doing something wrong here. I've been repairing computers professionally for over 12 years and have never run into something like this.

Does Windows 8 have something that thinks the data is some sort of Malware?

Comment: are you facing encryption to any level?

Comment: This sounds more like a file ownership permission problem.  Windows has built-in tools to transfer files contained within the user profile folders.

Comment: Take ownership of the whole folder from the security tab.